# Quo modo hoc situ uti possum nisi Anglice intellego?

Tags: support

Lingua Latina mihi cordi est et hoc situ uti volo.
Maxima pars situs Anglice scripta est, et Anglice minime legere possum.
Potestisne mihi Latine describere quo modo hunc situm adhibere possim?

Comment: Laudo hanc quaestionem!  Hoc situ debet utile stare pro quisque latina student.

Answer (score 6):

Ecce responsum breve; forsitan ceteri plus informationis dare possunt.
Hae sunt res maximi ponderis:

- Situs [linguae Latinae apud StackExchange](https://latin.stackexchange.com/) dedicatus est **quaestionibus et responsis** ad linguam Latinam pertinentibus.
  Hic rogare licet et ceteris respondere, sed discussiones et opiniones excludere conamur.
  Volumus enim paginas nostras variis hominibus, qui aliquid de hac lingua scire velint, usui fore; quam metam facillimum est petere quaestionibus claris et brevibus similibusque responsis.
- Si Anglice intellegis, fac [introductionem brevem (introductory tour)](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour) perlegas.
  Ibi cor systematis clare et breviter exponitur.
- Hic duabus linguis uti licet: Anglica et Latina.
  Fieri potest, ut aliquis scripta tua Latina in Anglicum reddat et versionem Anglicum iuxta tuum ponat, quo pluribus legibilis sit.
  Lingua Anglica utile est sed non necesse si hoc situ uti vis.
  Maxima pars quaestionum Anglice scribitur, sed semper Latine respondere licet.
- Si aliquid de lingua Latina rogare vis, fac [novam quaestionem scribas](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).
  Forsitan aliquis alius iam quaestionem tuam posuit; hortamur, ut [indicem quaestionum recentium](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) videas.
  Speramus te etiam aliquid in hoc indice invenire, cui respondere possis.
- Ecce aliquot exampla:

  - [Quid significat “-amen”?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/292/79)
  - [Quando “a fortiori” ortum est?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/295/79)
  - [Quomodo “cochlear” a “cochlea” est ortum?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/118/79)
  - [Accusativus 'Graecus' pertinetne ullo modo ad accusativum temporis?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/108/79)
- Si plus scire vis, fac roges.
  Tibi auxiliari volumus.

Bene adveneris apud nos!

Comment: If we are really going to have users who don't understand much English, we should have more instructions than this. Answers about our scope (what is off and on topic, closing and editing questions, comments to improve) and accounts (reputation, privileges, ability to edit and respond, pings) would be most welcome. I will remove this comment once the very basics of those things are covered in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Quibus a @JoonaIlmavirta scripta sunt addo hæc (nec qui errores a me facti animadvertet emendendo abstineat!):

—Cujusque rogati responsique ad lævam invenitur sagittæ sursum versumque vertantes duo, quibus alios existimari licet. Verbis tuis improbatis, noli spem dejicere; nemo te in odio habet (horum saltem verborum causa)! Aliquis vero fortasse verba enodanda enucleandave putat vel mage ad linguam ipsam pertinenda.

—Idonea sunt de lingua Latina rogata, de quomodo orta sit, de quid inter verba intersit diversa, de frasibus locisve difficilibus, et cetera. Inoptata sunt exempli gratia rogata de quemadmodum lingua Latina ad linguam Gallicam attineat vel de cultu moribusve Romanis (nisi lingua plicantur). Inoptata quoque sunt rogata in quæ rogator enixum non sit.

—Rogata nimium improbata inoptatave interdum delentur. Iterum noli spem dejicere. Alii qui situ utentur tibi auxilio esse possunt ad melius rogandum.

Salvus, salva sis! Speramus te situ multum frui!