# Updates to help pages

Tags: discussion, introductory-tour

I have made edits to several help pages to add site-specific content.
I followed the conclusion we reached in [a previous meta discussion about our scope](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/120/79).
This post has three purposes:

- announcing this change,
- recording the old versions for later reference, and
- asking for feedback

Did I overlook some place to edit?
Are the changes ok, or should something be changed?
I would prefer to keep our rules (the help pages) as simple and short as possible, and to only add more details if an actual need arises.

### [Tour](https://latin.stackexchange.com/tour)

The tour intro:

> **Latin Language Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for linguists, teachers, and students wanting to discuss the finer points of the Latin language. It's built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Latin language.

→

> **Latin Language Stack Exchange** is a question and answer site for linguists, teachers, and students wanting to discuss the finer points of the Latin language. It is built and run *by you* as part of the [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com) network of Q&A sites. With your help, we are working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about Latin language. We also allow questions about Ancient Greek; details can be found below or [on this meta page](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/358/79).
>
> *Si Anglice non intellegis et hoc situ uti vis, vide [hanc paginam Latine scriptam](http://meta.latin.stackexchange.com/q/168/79).*

We now have an example question actually related to Latin.
We cannot change the example question since there is only one eligible question now.
You can use [this SE Data Explorer query](http://data.stackexchange.com/latin/query/473660/possible-tour-questions-and-near-misses) to find questions that are fully or almost eligible.

Ask about:

> - Specific issues with Latin language
> - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered

→

> - Specific issues with Latin, such as with grammar, vocabulary or pronunciation
> - History and culture when there is a close relation to the Latin language
> - Latin literature
> - Real problems or questions that you’ve encountered
>
> We also allow questions about Greek up to the end of classical antiquity, including New Testament Greek. Questions on biblical Latin or Greek should focus on language.

I decided to keep the list in the tour simple.
A more detailed list is on the help pages, see below.

Don't ask:

> - Anything not directly related to Latin language
> - Questions that are primarily opinion-based
> - Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

→

> - Anything not directly related to the Latin language
> - Questions that are primarily opinion-based
> - Questions with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer
> - Questions that show [no research effort](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/143) using readily available online sources

### [Help front page](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help)

No text on this page.

→

> Si Anglice non intellegis et hoc situ uti vis, vide [hanc paginam Latine scriptam](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/168/79).

We cannot make a custom help page in Latin, but this text here on the help front page makes Latin help more visible.
This text is not very prominent, but it's better than nothing.

### [On-topic help](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Please [look around](/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](/helpcenter/self-answer).
>
> If your question is not specifically on-topic for $SiteName, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.

The $SiteName thing is automatically replaced with "Latin Language Stack Exchange".

→

> This site is for questions about the Latin language throughout its history. We welcome questions about all aspects of Latin language, its relation to other languages and also cultural and historical questions that are strongly related to Latin. The site is aimed for experts and students in the field. The site is not a translation service or a homework help center.
>
> Have a look around to get an idea what kinds of questions are welcome here. Possible topics include but may not be limited to the following:
>
> - Latin grammar, vocabulary, and pronunciation
> - etymology and relations to other languages
> - interpretation of difficult passages and works of literature in Latin
> - history and culture when directly about or when there is a strong connection to the Latin language
> - requests of examples in literature for uses of certain words or structures
>
> On the other hand, questions of the following kinds should generally not be asked here:
>
> - translation requests or etymological queries that show no serious research effort using readily available online sources
> - requests for homework help unless they show significant attempt to solve the problems without outside help (for guidance, see: [How can I ask a translation or homework question?](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/143/12))
>
> Questions may be asked and answered in English or Latin, preferably with an English summary if in Latin. If you are not fluent in either language, post your question in your language of preference and provide a rough translation to English or Latin.
>
> We also allow questions about Greek up to the end of classical antiquity, including New Testament Greek. Similarly, questions about small italic languages closely related to Latin are allowed. However, questions should not be asked in these languages. For more details about Greek (and the Bible), see [this meta post](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/358/79).
>
> Questions concerning biblical Latin or Greek should focus more on language than content. For questions about exegesis, philosophy, and to some extent literature, some [other Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) might be more appropriate. This is mainly a language site.
>
> Please [look around](/search) to see if your question has been asked before. It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](/helpcenter/self-answer).
>
> If your question is not specifically on-topic for $SiteName, it may be on topic for another Stack Exchange site. If no site currently exists that will accept your question, you may [commit to](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) or [propose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-can-i-propose-a-new-site) a new site at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/), the place where new Stack Exchange communities are democratically created.